# UITableViewHeaderFooterView's contentView size changes unexpectedly when selecting row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, fonts, accessibility

I have a problem with the section headings in a UITableView changing size when I select a row, making the table sections jump around when you tap on a row.

The app is using a custom font with dynamic sizing. I'm setting the font with

```
UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: <textStyle>).scaledFont(for: <font>, maximumPointSize: <maximumPointSize>)
```

I have a way to work around the problem with the default setting, but the problem returns with large accessibility font sizes.

The table consists of two sections. The section headings use the standard component. The first section (which typically contains three cells) uses a standard UITableViewCell. The second section has one custom cell, which when selected inserts a second custom cell with a picker (cf the way the start time cell opens a date picker in the iOS Calendar app). The extra cell is inserted using a beginUpdates/endUpdates block with insertRows.

Here is what happens: when the table is first rendered, the heading's contentView are much larger than the UILabel with the heading. If I tap on the cell in section 2 that opens the second cell, the headings contentView size is reduced to match the size of the label. It stays this way, unless I select one of the cells in the first section. At that point the headings are resized again, now with a contentSize smaller than the original but larger than it was at its smallest.

Here is what I have tried:

I had originally specified the table heading font size using

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self])
```

in the AppDelegate, which is where I deal with other types of components. However, it appears that the UITableView does not systematically observe this when reloading the table data, i.e. the font size itself would change during a table reload (not just the contentView size).

I changed the code to specify the font size in willDisplayHeaderView instead, i.e something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

        if let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
            if let textlabel = header.textLabel {
                textlabel.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for:Theme.font, maximumPointSize: 30)
            }
            if section == 0 {
              header.accessibilityLabel = ...
              header.accessibilityHint = ...
            } else {
              header.accessibilityLabel = ... 
              header.accessibilityHint = ... 
            }
```

This got rid of the problem with the font size changing when the table was redrawn. It also got rid of the problem with the heading's contentView size changing for the default font size. But once I switch up the font size in the accessibility settings, the heading contentView size change problem appears.

I have attempted to set the sectionHeaderHeight ("settings" is the UITableView)

```
self.settings.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
self.settings.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 60
```

This doesn't make a difference either.

If I were to guess, it looks like the heading sometimes resizes itself based on displaying a much larger UILabel, but why are the sizes different depending on how the table is redrawn?

I guess the next step is to replace the table heading with a custom view, but that seems like overkill.

What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of Custom View for section header you can use custom cell with single label

Comment: Return Header cell in 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
let cell = UITableviewcell()
cell.textlabel.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for:Theme.font, maximumPointSize: 30)
return cell
}

Comment: Hi Amita, using a cell to render a heading is an interesting hack! Since the reason that I am exploring this is accessibility, this won't work for VoiceOver, unless I also override the UIAccessibilityTraits for the cell. This may involve using a custom cell to work reliably. Worth trying if nothing else works but I would prefer to stay within the UITableViewHeaderFooterView idiom if possible.

Comment: If your question is still up to date, would you mind making available your entire table view code (Github for instance) to take a look at your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work without adding a custom header, so that is the solution I went with. The custom header uses rather an ugly workaround to control the height of the header.

My original implementation had this combo:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 0 {
            return "One"
        } else if section == 1 {
            return "Two"
        } else {
            // Should not happen
            return "Other"
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

        if let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView, let textlabel = header.textLabel {
            textlabel.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: ..., maximumPointSize: 23)
        }   
    }
```

Here is the workaround.

1. Register a custom header

```
<UITableView>.register(TableHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "Header")
```

2. "Custom" header with an invisible label that controls the size

```
class TableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    // Dummy invisible label that controls the size of the header
    let label = UILabel()

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.label.text = "M"
        self.label.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0)

        // Make sure VoiceOver doesn't see it
        self.label.isAccessibilityElement = false

        // Set the font 
        self.label.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: ..., maximumPointSize: 23)
        self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.label)

        let size = self.label.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height + 20),
            self.label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor, constant: 20),
            self.label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0)])

        self.label.text = " "
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

3. Load the custom header using viewForHeaderInSection

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        if let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "Header") as? TableHeaderView {

            if section == 0 {
                header.textLabel?.text = "One"
            } else if section == 1 {
                header.textLabel?.text = "Two"
            } else {
                // Should not happen
                header.textLabel?.text = "Other"
            }
            return header
        }

        return nil
    }
```